# C++ pointer changes address with Visual Studio, not with Xcode in OsX or gcc in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, pointers

I have a c++ problem which has been puzzling my mind for hours: I have a class which contains a map of items to which I need to make pointer references; everything works fine under Osx and Linux but when running my program built with MSVC under Windows seems like the address of items in map and also the base address of the map changes depending on the function of my class that uses it so my pointer point to something they souldn't; does someone know of some obscure compiler option that can do something like that?

```
class Base {
   std::map <uint64_t, long> items ;

   ...

   void functA() {
      std::cout << "FunctA: " << &items ;
   }

   void functB() {
      std::cout << "FunctB: " << &items ;
   }
}
```

...

```
void main() {
      Base a ;
      ...
      a.functA() ;
      a.functB() ;
   }
```

Output calling functA and functB might be for example:

Linux/OsX
FunctA: 013FF7A0
FunctB: 013FF7A0

Windows:
FunctA: 013FF900
FunctB: 013FF7A0

I've also tryed pointing to iterators but they do same thing what I've understood from c++ docs is that for maps elements have fixed addresses, they change only for deleted items.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. `functA` and `functB` are *member* functions, so you can't just "call" them. You need an object on which you invoke them.

Comment: Yes you are right, I've omitted part of the code; I create a "Base" object and then call the functions

Comment: Your problem is in the code you're not showing.

Comment: That code you posted is fiction. There's no `Main` (it should be `main`). Please paste the exact code you're using to create the problem, from your editor.

Comment: Also, if you're on unix try running valgrind to see if you've got any memory errors. But yeah, the issue is in the code you're not showing.

Comment: @kerrek-sb: yes, the code is fictional because it's a big project I've started under OsX and after a while tryed to build under Windows so went into problems with it being a lot of code that would be too long to post here so I've tryed to make some short version of what I guess is the minimal thing causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very subtle but I've found the solution, the fact is that evidently GCC and XCode compiler make an implicit new while MSVC does not so the object was not allocated in the free store and that was messing things up under Windows, everything got fine by changing the source code to this:

```
 class Base {
   std::map <uint64_t, long> items ;

   ...

   void functA() {
      std::cout << "FunctA: " << &items ;
   }

   void functB() {
      std::cout << "FunctB: " << &items ;
   }
}

...

void main() {
      Base* a ;
      a = new Base() ;
      ...
      a.functA() ;
      a.functB() ;
   }
```

Especially the problem got evident when passing pointers to "Base" objects to other threads that were getting all wrong data.